# Selecting jquery objects by id vs by classname

Tags: javascript, jquery

Which one is more preferable while selecting objects with jquery.

By classnames `$('.my-element')` or id `$('#myElement')`

As I know jquery uses browser native functions `getElementById()` and `getElementsByClassName()` for them.

But I guess selecting objects with `Id` must be simpler and faster.

So why any modern approach (like bootstrap for example) suggest to use `className`?

Is it logical to use className for a unique dom object which will be used once.

Thank you.

Comment: 1 reason could be id must be unique, so if you want to group similar element then class will be a better approach

Comment: with class you can target multiple elements

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/

Answer (score 5):

ID for single elements that have an ID. I believe that this is the fastest way to locate a single element.

Class names for multiple elements or elements without an ID

Answer (score 2):

Well, it also depends if you want to select ALL the elements with a certain class VS a single element. It's on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 0):

If an element has an id, use it.

If you want to select all elements that have a specific class, use a class.

They're really meant for two separate things rather than alternatives to each other.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is what you are after, and im assuming you are. Generally Selecting by id works fastest, then speedwise, by class then by element. If an element has an id, you should generally use it.. If you have more than one element, and you want a selector to create an array, because you would like to do something with those elements, you would use a class.
I hope this answers your qustion.

Answer (score 0):

`Id` is unique for each element, but `class name` can be applied in multiple elements. If you want operate`multiple elements then class name is good approach else ID is good approach`.

Answer (score 0):

It is depends upon your requirement.In some cases you need to select with id or name or class.

If you want to select a single element you can use ID. Because it is unique.

If you want to select multiple elements you can use class. Because if you need to do some action for multiple elements you can use class as a selector.

Answer (score 0):

An `Id` is more specific than a `class`, but can be applied on only 1 element per page.
A `class` can be applied on more elements. 
Bottom line: depends on how many elements you want to be affected or how specific your rule should be

Answer (score -1):

the best best will be selecting them in javascript then create a jquery object with it:

```
var obj = document.getElementById('element_id');
var $obj = $(obj);
```

but nobody does that ;) ... you can use classname or id directly in jQuery and this is the way to go ... ID will be a little bit faster.

hope that helps!

Comment: So it's the best way, yet nobody ever uses it? Yeah that's a no.

Comment: This is pointless. I would even go as far as saying this is *actually* stupid.

Comment: I have actually benchmarked this in the past and the difference is so negligible it is almost not even worth noting.

Comment: The best way is not to have `varName` *and* `$varName` for every reference.